# Windows 10 Installation on a SSD error: " We couldn't create a new partition..."

Tags: windows, installation

I have an Acer Nitro 5 with a Gigabyte 512gb ssd and a WD 1TB hhd.
Recently after installing Ubuntu on my hdd (because i didn't want to change the sata mode), I also wanted a clean Windows install. So I created a boot usb from
 media creation tool and go forward with it.
It didn't work. I got the "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one" error, which i spent a significant amount of time trying to search for a solution.

Stuffs i tried:
- Format my ssd
- use diskpart to clean, convert my ssd partition table to gpt, etc like every guide online recommends.
- Make another boot usb, this time with rufus. Didn't work.

Stuffs I didn't try:
- Temporarily disconnect my hdd. I don't have the tools to do that physically, and my acer uefi has zero options regarding this, like most guides suggests.
- Change to bios-legacy boot mode. There's no option in the uefi.

I think it would be fine if i try to install windows on my hdd though, but haven't try it yet. All I know is installing windows on a ssd is much harder but didn't expect it to produce this much annoyance.

I heard there's an option to install on a HDD, the. use a third party tool to copy it to a SSD, but i haven't look into it.

Thanks for any help given..

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site by taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages.

Comment: I had that problem, and adding some empty space between partitions solved it. Just make the Windows partition smaller by 500Mb or so.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you have Windows 10 installed and working** on your SSD go to `Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Reset this PC > Get started` and then select if you want your files kept you want clean reinstall. Again - from your post I assume the latter so just click `Remove everything"` confirm and wait. It will take (depending on the machine) 1-2 hours.

I've found this to be the easiest way to have clean install without wondering how do I get it installed on my laptop/pc.

My recommendation though - back up your ubuntu partition - I can't guarantee that windows installer won't clean up HDD you have (it's supposed to clean only SSD but better be safe than sorry).

[Here's the link to detailed instructions](https://news.softpedia.com/news/how-the-new-reset-feature-works-in-windows-10-version-1903-524501.shtml). It's based on 1903 compilation - if your's older it will still look very similar.

**If your windows isn't working** then use diskpart to clean the drive, boot the computer from USB windows installation stick and choose the drive for your installation - it will/should create appropriate partitions and start installing.

**If it won't change boot order so the SSD is first on the list and HDD next** and repeat the previous step.